# Google App Engine API method response perfectly alternating between correct and wrong result

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, eventual-consistency

I am currently working on the udacity course on Google-App-Engine (https://www.udacity.com/course/ud859). 
There are Profiles and Conferences. Each Profile can register for conferences which then get added to a List in the Profile object.

When I have a look now at my API Explorer of the "getProfile" request (which retrieves the user data for the currently active user, authenticated by oAuth2.0) I get different results each time that I click on "Execute".

When I click on execute for the first time I get the right response:

**Correct response** (I validated this via the developers console datastore query):

```
200 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "displayName": "matjes993",
 "mainEmail": "matjes993@gmail.com",
 "teeShirtSize": "L",
 "conferenceKeysToAttend": [
  "ag9zfnVkYWNpdHk2MTNuZXdyMwsSB1Byb2ZpbGUiFTExMTAxNDEyMTM0NDI2MTgyNTQwOAwLEgpDb25mZXJlbmNlGJJODA",
  "ag9zfnVkYWNpdHk2MTNuZXdyNAsSB1Byb2ZpbGUiFTExMTAxNDEyMTM0NDI2MTgyNTQwOAwLEgpDb25mZXJlbmNlGLHqAQw"
 ],
 "userId": "111014121344261825408",
 "kind": "conference#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"E9X210UxHC5oxQ1CO9nNLV3Nj2U/3Ht-GWsemcXnzWP_cuR_xoRfQxM\""
}
```

But if I click on execute again I get the following response:

**Wrong response**

```
200 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "displayName": "matjes993",
 "mainEmail": "matjes993@gmail.com",
 "teeShirtSize": "L",
 "conferenceKeysToAttend": [
  "ag9zfnVkYWNpdHk2MTNuZXdyMwsSB1Byb2ZpbGUiFTExMTAxNDEyMTM0NDI2MTgyNTQwOAwLEgpDb25mZXJlbmNlGJJODA"
 ],
 "userId": "111014121344261825408",
 "kind": "conference#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"E9X210UxHC5oxQ1CO9nNLV3Nj2U/FsMMRtBBI307rMvfLGhJOG_P8uI\""
}
```

If I click execute again I do get the correct response again and so forth. It is always alternating between wrong and right, but the data in the datastore query stays the same. This doesn´t make sense to me at all.

The getProfile method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public Profile getProfile(final User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
    }

    String userId = user.getUserId();
    Key<Profile> key = Key.create(Profile.class, userId);

    Profile profile =  ofy().load().key(key).now();
    return profile;
}
```

UPDATE 1:
Even now, 12 hours later, the problem is still there. I see the correct data in the developers console but my frontend as well as the API Explorer is always switching between the correct and the wrong result.
It almost feels as there are two different datastores underneath and the API calls alternate between them..?

UPDATE 2:
I redeployed the app into a new project on GAE but the error is still happening. I altered the above post as I now have a more simple example when the issue occurs.